# Reformatting vim files

Tags: vim, notepad++

**SOLVED, see my answer. However, I figure this question is still a good learning exp for other novices like myself**

So I am working on this project, but I am working on it both at home and at work.

The project is written in `python`.

The problem I am running into is that, at work I use notepadd++ on windows.

My tab settings are as follows for notepad++:

- tab=4 columns, but

  - do NOT expand the tab to actually = 4 spaces

I then send the files to myself in an email and download them at home. When I open the files in vim on my Linux box, the same number of tabs are there, but all of the tabs take up 8 columns, not actually replaced by spaces.

I don't know why this is happening, but is there some command I can use to reformat the files according to my `.vimrc`?

`gg=G` sort of works but doesn't quite do the job

My settings are as follows:

```
"se t_Co=256   
syntax enable

set mouse=a  
set tabstop=4  
set softtabstop=4  
set shiftwidth=4   
"set expandtab     
set number   
set showcmd   
set cursorline     
set showmatch    

execute pathogen#infect()    
filetype plugin indent on

"folding settings  
set foldmethod=indent         
set foldnestmax=10           
set nofoldenable              
set foldlevel=1
```

**EDIT:** whatever it does under the hood to try to convert it, it seems like its not doing it recursively or something. Its hard to explain, so let me give some screen shots.

Here's a portion of a file I just opened in vim, unedited:
[image]

You can see how the tabs are 8 columns but they should be 4

Now, i type gg=G to "fix" indenting.
[image]
For the first method/first statement in that method, it worked as intended. But all the statements after it are left alone

It is also only the first METHOD that gets fixed, but for all other compund statements (for loops, try blocks etc.), that pattern of the first line being corrected, but nothing else being corrected occurs, it's like the algorithm isn't recurring. (or recursing, whatever)

Comment: Is your .vimrc getting source?  Put another way, do the tab settings work as expected for documents you create on the linux box?  And it's unusal that you have `set expandtab`, when you have the equivalent disabled in Notepad++ . . .

Comment: yeah it works normally. and I actually just put the expand tab in there today when I was playing around with stuff

Comment: Try `:set list` and `:set listchars=tab:t\ "` so you can see the tabs while you look for issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, like some of you suggested, it wasn't grabbing the correct source, I suspect it's because it is a DOS file. fixed by typing:

```
:source ~/.vimrc
```

at the ed command line

Answer (score 1):

To get tabs to be 4 columns in vim, use:

```
set shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4
```

If, more specifically, you only want these tab settings when editing python files, then put the following in your ~/.vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.py set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

Comment: these are already my vimrc settings

Comment: With a python file open in vim, type `:set`.  This shows your current settings.  What does it show for expandtab, tabstop and shiftwidth?